# How to automate web scraper selector rules?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am planning to automate web scraper selector rules.Currently we are using selenium to scrape web pages. And its universal problem that websites tend to change their DOM structure. Is there a way to automate the process if the particular rule breaks then it should restructure the rules based on new DOM structure. I know its extremely difficult to do it when the Dom structure completely changes. But is there way to identify and fix leaves level changes?

As far as I know there are no python framework to give a direct solution to it.is there any python library which I should take to help me in this?

Comment: How would you propose your program change itself (the rules of it..) based on a new DOM structure that is unknown? It's a general problem with web scraping with no quick fix. Based upon what you're scraping for you could try scraping according to content rather than DOM structure. This may or may not help your scraper survive longer.

Comment: Like Pythonista already said, the only way I can think of is scraping based on content itself. Maybe some kind of machine-learning neural network thingy, but that seems a rather overkill compared to just changing the scraping rules. Another thing is of course to use a site-specific API if they provide that kind of service, but that is most of the time not the case.

Comment: its looks like we need to develop a framework to understand DOM structure and make changes to the existing selectors...